# At what level Eevee will evolve?

Tags: pokemon-uranium

I got my Eevee at level 20 and it's holding a Thunderstone because I want it to become a Jolteon, but I already leveled it up twice and it didn't evolve.

After checking the Wiki, I thought it was like the Nucleon (leveling Eevee to 20+ with a Nuclear type in your party) but I guess I was wrong.

So, what do I need to do to evolve my Eevee?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use the Thunder Stone on it

The [Thunder Stone](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Evolutionary_stone#Thunder_Stone) is one of a group of items called Evolutionary Stones. All of them are activated by entering your inventory, selecting to Use the item, then choosing the Pokémon you want to evolve with it. This will consume the stone and cause the Pokémon to immediately evolve. The level of your Pokémon has no bearing on when you can evolve it with an Evolutionary Stone. This is how you evolve Eevee into [Jolteon](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Jolteon_(Pok%C3%A9mon)).

A full list of methods for evolving Eevee (through the current generation, but not including methods specific to the fangame Pokémon Uranium) can be found at the top of [its Bulbapedia page](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Eevee_(Pok%C3%A9mon)).

Comment: That's it. The Eevee just evolved into Jolteon. Thanks!